# Android - Mediarecorder outputformat to base64

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am developing audio recorder application in android. My aim is to record the audio and send it to my webservice method. The code snippet of record audio is given below.

```
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private static String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

private void startRecording() {
     mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
     mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
     mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
     mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
     mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
     try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
     }
     mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}
```

In the above code the output file has stored in the **"mFileName"** path. Now I am getting the output and it stored into specified "ExternalStorageDirectory" path. But I don't want to store the output file into the "ExternalStorageDirectory". I want to convert the output into base64 string. Can anyone help me to do this?

```
Objective:
    1) I don't want to store the output in local.
    2) Convert the output into base64 string.
```

Comment: what's wrong with storing first before encoding it? (also, you'll need a pretty big string if you record a long time, and memory will be an issue)

Comment: Thanks njzk2. The recorded voice should be secured in my app. So that I don't want to store in local(I am recording audio only 5 seconds. So the output string will be a small one). Is it possible to convert the output as base64.

Comment: your record goes to file system. but you can put it in the private directory of your application

Comment: ok thanks. Can you give me some samples to put the file in private directory of myapplication.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html see the getDir method